# ios: sample source looks like ios address book

Tags: ios, addressbook

in my project, i'm going to implement a app very like the ios address book. however, the native address book framework doesn't conform my requirement, you know ios address book framework doesn't allow further customization.

hence, do you know any third party project/sample we can use to make further customization on it?? Or any other idea would be appreciate.

Thanks

Comment: I've removed the `book` tag since that refers to hardcopy and digital textbooks and reference materials, rather than address books, contact lists and any other compilation of information that an app may generate/possess.